# Does sqlite support any kind of IF(condition) statement in a select

Tags: sql, sqlite

Does sqlite support the sql function "if" in the select statement?

for example

```
select if( length( a ) > 4 , a , ' ') as b
from foo
```

which would return a if the length was over 4 chars long. or else it would return ' ' as b

If it does support a condition in the select what is the syntax is should be using?

I have checked  http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html but I can't see it.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

See the [case](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) expression.

> A CASE expression serves a role similar to IF-THEN-ELSE in other programming languages.

For your example

```
select case when length(a) > 4 then a else '' end as b
from foo
```

Comment: dunno why they can't also have a shorter syntax for simple things like the ternary operator in C.... imagine how long the query can be when stringing together several case statements !

Answer (score 18):

You can use [case](http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) for that:

```
select case when length(a)>4 then a else ' ' end from foo;
```

Comment: Odd; the link doesn't work for iceweasel. It will cause a Document Not Found Error (/lang_5Fexpr.html). The address in the address-bar will be the correct one though (.../lang_expr.html). Not sure why that is. Although the address is correct, a refresh won't work; have to hit enter in the address bar to get the page.

Comment: markdown doesn't like underscores I guess. I have changed the link to use the snurl redirector

Comment: and you should not use a redirector [ so direct URL is now there

Answer (score 6):

Since version [3.32.0](https://sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_32_0) you can use [iif(X,Y,Z)](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#iif):

```
select iif( length( a ) > 4 , a , ' ') as b
from foo
```

From the codumentation:

> The iif(X,Y,Z) function is logically equivalent to and generates the same bytecode as the CASE expression "CASE WHEN X THEN Y ELSE Z END".