# Is there an sqlite function that can check if a field matches a certain value and return 0 or 1?

Tags: sqlite, sql

Consider the following **sqlite3** table:

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| 1    | 200  |
| 1    | 200  |
| 1    | 100  |
| 1    | 200  |
| 2    | 400  |
| 2    | 200  |
| 2    | 100  |
| 3    | 200  |
| 3    | 200  |
| 3    | 100  |
+------+------+
```

I'm trying to write a query that will select the entire table and return 1 if the value in `col2` is 200, and 0 otherwise. For example:

```
+------+--------------------+
| col1 | SOMEFUNCTION(col2) |
+------+--------------------+
| 1    | 1                  |
| 1    | 1                  |
| 1    | 0                  |
| 1    | 1                  |
| 2    | 0                  |
| 2    | 1                  |
| 2    | 0                  |
| 3    | 1                  |
| 3    | 1                  |
| 3    | 0                  |
+------+--------------------+
```

What is SOMEFUNCTION()?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You could use something like what is described in [this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite, boolean values are just integer values 0 and 1, so you can use the comparison directly:

```
SELECT col1, col2 = 200 AS SomeFunction FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

Like described in [Does sqlite support any kind of IF(condition) statement in a select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294619/does-sqlite-support-any-kind-of-ifcondition-statement-in-a-select) you can use the case keyword.

```
SELECT col1,CASE WHEN col2=200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS col2 FROM table1
```